# Hatch pattern instead of solid fill to highlight selected polygons?

Tags: qgis

Can I highlight selected polygons with a hatch pattern instead of solid fill (I know that fill transparency is an option)? Either globally or on a project basis?

Comment: I guess the question is more "how" than "is it possible"? Can you add some more information, i.e. is there an attribute? Maybe also add a sample picture to demonstrate what you need.

Comment: I will add a screenshot shortly. There are attributes, but they are (IMHO) irrelevant. My questions is can I (or how can I) have QGIS display selected polygon(s) with a hatch pattern instead of a solid fill? I have all sorts of options to style all polygons, including hatch, but for a selected set I can only choose from different colors for solid fill.

Comment: Oh, now I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a partial way with rule-based symbology but you get only the hatch on top of the selection color, if you make selection 100% transparent you get a simple hatch fill

[image]

Comment: Careful, the isselected expression need to have the plugin Expression Plus installed